# CCDirector drawScene causing crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I've developing a game using Cocos2d and i'm having this error and i'm pretty stumped on why its happening or where its happening. Here is the stack trace:

```
-[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo swapBuffers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167dc160
BrainPlus-[CCDirectorIOS drawScene]

0   CoreFoundation  0x2ecf5f4b  __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x390856af  objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  0x2ecf98e7  -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
3   CoreFoundation  0x2ecf81cb  ___forwarding___
4   CoreFoundation  0x2ec474d8  _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5   AppName 0x002bde53  -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene]
6   QuartzCore  0x3113f9cf  _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv
7   QuartzCore  0x3113f779  _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy
8   IOMobileFramebuffer 0x33d2476d  IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc
9   IOKit   0x2f9d7a75  IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage
10  CoreFoundation  0x2ecb5e21  __CFMachPortPerform
11  CoreFoundation  0x2ecc09df  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
12  CoreFoundation  0x2ecc097b  __CFRunLoopDoSource1
13  CoreFoundation  0x2ecbf14f  __CFRunLoopRun
14  CoreFoundation  0x2ec29c27  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15  CoreFoundation  0x2ec29a0b  CFRunLoopRunInMode
16  GraphicsServices    0x33908283  GSEventRunModal
17  UIKit   0x314cd049  UIApplicationMain
18  AppName 0x00098191  main in main.m on Line 15
19  libdyld.dylib   0x3958dab7  start
```

I'm using sprite sheet for animations and the testers have said that the crash happens when the animations are occurring, but i've this error has come out of the blue. I'm wondering if anyone has had an error like this before and what has caused this crash. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of cocos2d are you using? I am having similar problems with my newest app, which is using cocos2d-v3. Will investigate, it might be a memory leak, which leads to a wrong pointer, hence the doesNotRecognizeSelector.

Comment: Is this with a release build of an app? What's the compiler optimization setting? If it's "smallest & fastest" change it, cocos2d has had issues with that optimization setting before. Which cocos2d version are you using?

Comment: using COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00020100